# Dynamic nested TableColumn's

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I'm very new on JavaFX and I'm trying to fill a TableView, these columns are filled dynamically. my stuck is that from the second column and so on must be nested, for example, Column2 must have two or X nested columns and so on... I'm fetching the data using this...For example

```
ObservableList<ObservableList>data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
while(rs2.next()){
  ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
  if(rs2.getInt("connectionid")!=0){
   row.add(rs2.getString("tdestname"));
   row.add(rs2.getBigDecimal("tdusdprice").toString()); // Dynamic fields...
   row.add(rs2.getBigDecimal("tdeurprice").toString());
   ......
   data.add(row);
  }
}
tvRates.setItems(data);
```

After these, my TableView can't show the data, Can you teach me how I can read the fetched data on my nested columns ?

Comment: is tvRates a `TableView` ? ,where did you instantiate it and how ? the code that you shared has nothing to do with dynamic nested columns using `javafx` `TableView.

Comment: TableView documentation : http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm#CJAGAAEE

Comment: For nested columns use getColumns() method of TableColumn : http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/index.html